# TikZ externalization with floatrow package

Tags: tikz-external, floatrow

When using the TikZ externalization library within a `\ffigbox` from the [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package, the external image is created two times. The reason is, that the argument of `\ffigbox` gets parsed two times. Obviously the result is as expected, but I would nevertheless like to prevent the generation of those unnecessary duplicates. How can one achieve that?

Here's a MWE to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
  \ffigbox{\tikz{\node{a};}}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Please note that using `\tikzsetnextfilename` does avoid the duplicate files. However the external image will contain two pages with the same content. So, strictly speaking, this does not prevent the redundancy.

Comment: I guess you need to dig in the bowels of the package and add `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` around the 2nd parsing of the file argument. Maybe possible with the `\patchcmd` command from `etoolbox?`

Comment: @MartinH Thanks for suggesting `\patchcmd` – I wasn't aware of it. But I was already fearing I would need to dive in the code of `floatrow.sty` and had a quick look. I am not sure if I can read that (it looks a lot like Fortran to me...)

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary solution I propose a dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifFBgettingBox
\let\OldFBget@box\FBget@box
\renewcommand\FBget@box[3]{%
  \FBgettingBoxtrue%
  \OldFBget@box{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \FBgettingBoxfalse}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{calc} % needed just for demonstration

\begin{document}
  \ffigbox{
    \ifFBgettingBox
      \rule{\widthof{a}}{\heightof{a}}
    \else
      \tikz{\node{a};}
    \fi
  }{}
\end{document}
```

Obviously a real use case would look more complicated, but often one is in the lucky position of knowing width and height of one's graphics. (In the example I worked around it with the help of `\widthof{a}` from the [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package.)

Of course it is annoying to type the if clause every time one uses a `\ffigbox`. This may be circumvented by defining a macro.

I would have preferred a solution using `\tikzifexternalizing` or similar. The problem with this approach is, that when disabling externalization of a usually externalized image *only* during externalization itself, makes the externalization dizzy...